# How to Import Private key with Public Address

Tags: javascript, web3js, private-key, account, go-ethereum

I made several accounts with some commands `personal.newAccount()`
and the accounts created were push to the list.
What I want to do is, get private key with public key that I've got with `getAccount()` function because of security reason.

I don't want to show my owner address and public key so I want to get address from list using the function.

```
web3.eth.getAccounts(); 
//["0x407d73d8a49eeb85d32cf465507dd71d507100c1"]
```

Then, I want to get the private key with that address like this way below.

```
var publicKey = web3.eth.getAccounts();
var privateKey = extractPrivateKey(pulicKey);
```

Is there any way to do like this using web3?
Is there some way to access the keystore on javascript file?
I have to use `sendTransaction()` function in javascript code but it needs the privateKey to sign. Now I'm storing the privateKey as static and I think is quite dangerous.
I'm figuring out to hide my owner public and private key in the code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all this line of code `var publicKey = web3.eth.getAccounts();` doesn't return you the public key, it returns you an array of addresses.

You could use the npm package **keythereum**.
It extracts the private Key from your Keystore-File by passing the specific address. First you use the `importFromFile` function to import it and then use the `recover` function to extract the private key.

It would look like this:

```
var keystorePath = "/yourPathToTheKeystoreFile";

async function importPrivateKey(address) {
let methodName = ">>> [importPrivateKey]: ";
  try{

      var keyObject = await keythereum.importFromFile(address, keystorePath);

      var privateKey = await keythereum.recover(password, keyObject);

      return privateKey;


    }catch(e) {
      console.log(e);
      throw e;
    }
}
```

Now you can just call this function directly in any other function and use the extracted private key directly as a new parameter for the `sendTransaction`function without storing the private Key in any variable.